# Is native platforms: junit-4.11.jar, junit-LICENSE.html normal in Play Store?

Tags: java, android, junit, google-play

I've uploaded an app to the Play Store and have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why it's supported by 0 devices. I noticed that the APK has native platforms: junit-4.11.jar, junit-LICENSE.html. Is that normal? All other fields in the APK details seem normal.

Comment: Why did you upload Junit in your app? Are you using Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

junit-4.11.jar and junit-License.html causes problem of supporting 0 devices on playstore.

Please check which library or jar file in your is using this. Then you have to remove them and then upload your app.

In my case, core.jar had these files, just open the jar file using winrar, go to lib folder and delete these 2 files. There will be no problem in functioning of jar file by doing this.